# Can anyone help me solve this (p → r) → (¬a v b), p → q, b → s, q → r, ¬a → s // (r v s)

Tags: symbolic-logic

I have been working almost three days on this problem and I can't to this answer:

1. (p → r) → (¬a v b)
2. p → q
3. b → s
4. q → r
5. ¬a → s

// (r v s)

Comment: this is a moderately easy problem... but the way to answer it depends greatly on the rules of inference that you have access to... Also, how far have you gotten, what things do you notice about it?

Comment: The rules of inference I've been provided with are: Commutative, associative, distributive, identity, negation, double negation, idempotent, universal bound, De Morgan`s, absortion and conditional. I started to solve the problem, but when I get to the third premise it got really messy... I guess I´m doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3):

*Hint*

Assume **p** and derive **r** from 2. and 4. and then derive **p → r** by **→**-intro (*Conditional Proof*).

Now derive **¬a v b** from 1. by **→**-elim (*Modus Ponens*) and use **v**-elim (*Proof by Cases*) to derive **s**.

Conclude with **r v s** by **v**-intro (*addition*).

---

A different way (using [Rules of inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_rules_of_inference)) is:

A) apply [Hypothetical syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothetical_syllogism) to 2. and 4. to derive:

B) **p → r**

Apply [Modus ponens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens) to 1) and B) to derive:

c) **¬a v b**

Apply [Disjunction elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_elimination) to 3., 5. and C) to derive:

D) **s**

Finally, apply [Addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_introduction) to conclude with:

> > **r v s**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when you say "assume p" you mean to give values (true and false) to p?

Comment: @Joseph - No; it is the way to start a [Conditional Proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_proof).

Comment: I finally got it! Thanks all for your help...

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully people will forgive my logic being slightly rusty, but here's my complete proof (I came up with it independently of @Mauro's answer but they end up being quite similar, except that mine has the details filled in):

1. (p → r) → (¬a v b)
2. p → q
3. b → s
4. q → r
5. ¬a → s

---

6.a) Suppose p.
b) Then q (→ elimination, 6a and 2)
c) Then r (→ elimination, 6b and 4)
7. p → r (→ introduction, 6a-c)
8. (¬a v b) (→ elimination, 7 and 1)
9. Case analysis on (¬a v b)
a) Suppose ¬a
b) s (→ elimination, 9a and 5)
c) r v s (v introduction)
d) Suppose b
e) s (→ elimination, 9d and 3)
f) r v s (v introduction)
10. r v s (v elimination, 9a - 9f). QED